# Меняем форму загрузки CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

В CKEditor есть модуль по работе с изображениями и он использует FileUpload для быстрой загрузки файлов на сервер:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="0" class="cke_dialog_ui_input_file" role="presentation" id="cke_165_fileInput" title="Загрузить на сервер" src="javascript:void(0)">
    <html dir="ltr" lang="ru"><head><title></title></head><body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden; background: transparent;"><form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" dir="ltr" lang="ru" action=".ckfsys-master/connectors/php/upload.php?Type=Image&amp;CKEditor=wysiwyg&amp;CKEditorFuncNum=0&amp;langCode=ru">
<label id="cke_164_label" for="cke_164_label" style="display:none">Загрузить на сервер</label>
<input style="width:100%" id="cke_165_fileInput_input" aria-labelledby="cke_164_label" type="file" name="upload" size=""></form><script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(204);window.onbeforeunload = function() {window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(205)}</script></body></html>
    </iframe>
```

Я пытаюсь добавить непосредственно в форму дополнительный `input`, но не могу понять как модифицировать этот модуль изнутри. Пытался заменить форму через внешний скрипт:

```
$("#cke_165_fileInput_input").ready(function(){
  $("#cke_165_fileInput_input").append('<input type=text>');
});
```

Но, тоже ни чего не выходит, не добавляет html и всё, а почему - не могу понять.

Кто нибудь может подсказать, как всё-таки можно добавить код инпута в модуль загрузки?

Comment: Может из-за iframe  такая ерунда.

Comment: Судя по содержимому `iframe`, у вас нет элементса с `id="cke_158_label"`

Comment: Попробуйте вместо .ready() использовать .load()

Comment: Честно, не в курсе скопировал видимо другой вариант, подправил ...

Comment: сам $("#cke_165_fileInput_input").ready(function() - срабатывает!

Comment: У меня такое ощущение, что в этой системе скрипт подгружаеться в конце и всё ломает. :(